# Is there a simple way to get days as Integers in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a daily reminder. For example, I want to know how many days have passed from a task. One more important thing, I want days to be integers (e.g. day->0 day->1), so I can put them in an Arraylist and use it later.
Is there any good way to do this? I don't want something like counter or things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try helpers from java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit example implementation can be found https://beginnersbook.com/2017/10/java-8-calculate-days-between-two-dates/.

To calculate the days between two dates we can use the DAYS.between() method of java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.

```
long noOfDaysBetween = DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
// or alternatively
long noOfDaysBetween = startDate.until(endDate, DAYS);

(The startDate is Inclusive and endDate is Exclusive in the calculation of noOfDaysBetween)
```